# camera open in android studio

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

this is my code:

```
        @TargetApi(9)
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
            Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
            mCamera = Camera.open(cameraID);
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");

            // XXX stopPreview() will crash if preview is not running
            if (mPreviewRunning){
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }

            Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
            p.setPreviewSize(300, 300);

            mCamera.setParameters(p);
            try{
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }catch (Exception e){
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mPreviewRunning = true;
            mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.e(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
            //mCamera.stopPreview();
            //mPreviewRunning = false;
            //mCamera.release();
        }

        private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
        private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
```

it fails in: `mCamera.setParameters(p);`
someone can help?

[image: crash log screenshot]

Comment: `it fails` how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Your device does not support preview 300x300 pixels, that's why `Cmaera.setParameters()` fails. You can only call `CameraParameters.setPreviewSize()` for one of the sizes listed in `CameraParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()`.

Few notes:

- If your device has more than one camera, each has its own list of supported sizes; some sizes may be supported by both cameras, others are not.
- In some rare cases, some devices may throw **RuntimeException** even if you choose one of sizes that is returned by `getSupportedPreviewSizes()`. These are platform bugs, you can keep a blacklist of such cases per model/platform. But in any case, don't forget to wrap `setParameters()` in `try … catch` and try to resolve the issue.
- In some rare cases, some devices may *not throw* **RuntimeException** but simply ignore the preview size request (or some other parameter). Be prepared.
- **android.hardware.Camera** class is deprecated. For devices with Android Lollipop (21) and higher, use the **[android.hardware.camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)** API.

Comment: i need to enter (int,int) in  p.setPreviewSize(HERE)

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: excuse me, what explanation is missing?  
here is an example code for you: stackoverflow.com/a/21404771/192373